# Change the current fragment of ViewPager from other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `Fragment` which contains `viewpager`.

inside `ViewPager` I have 3 more Fragments, `Fragment-A`,`Fragment-B`, and `Fragment-C`.

Inside `Fragment A` I have a `Button`, in `Button` `onClick()`  I want to change the current item to `Fragment C`.

How can I achieve it? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If button is not in main fragment, you'll have to define an interface to communicate between your main fragment and sub fragments i.e fragment A B C.

```
public interface GoToNextFragment {
void onGoToFragment(int index);
}
```

Your MainFragmet will have to implement this interface and the method that goes with it :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements GoToNextFragment {
//Your regular methods...
@Override
public void onGoToFragment(index) {
if (myAdapter != null) {
myAdapter.setCurrentItem(index);
}
}
```

Still in your MainFragment, set the interface on your fragments :

```
fragment1.setInterface(this);
fragment2.setInterface(this);
```

In your Fragments, add the setInterface method :

```
private GoToNextFragment mInterface;

public void setInterface(GoToNextFragment i) {
mInterface = i;
}
```

And finally in fragment a, trigger the effect with :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (mInterface != null) {
  mInterface.onGoToFragment(2);
}
});
```

Comment: How can I get the instance of  Fragment 1 like fragment.setInterface(this)?

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get the instance of Fragment1 in MainFragment?

Comment: why do you want to get the instance of Fragment1 in MainFragment?

Comment: to get the instance of Fragment1 in your MainFragment you will have to define a function in Fragment1 which will return the instance of Fragment1 to MainFragment.

Comment: by using fragment1.setinterface(this) we are sending the context of MainFragment to the fragment1. There is no need to get the instance of fragment1 here.
sorry my bad i took your question wrong

Comment: Getting mInterface null in onClick method

Comment: have you set fragment1.setinterface(this) in MainFragment?

Comment: Yes after setting the viewpager adapter. I call the set fragment method and it gives the address Timber.d("Interface st--1--${mInterface.toString()}") logs correctly

Comment: But when I access the mInterface object inside onClick method. It returns null

Comment: are you putting the same object of fragment1 to the viewpager which you use to set interface in fragment1.setinterface(this)? it is showing null because you have not used the same object for setting interface and for assigning fragment to viewpager

Comment: Yes you are right. can you please help me in creating the static fragment object. I tried with adapter.getCurrentItem. It's not working. Thanks

Comment: you can do it in very simple way don't go for static object. just make an array list or array of fragments and put fragment1, frargment2 and fragment3 in that array. send this array to the viewpager adapter using adapter costructor. now on overrided function "getitem" use that array to get fragments in the positions respectively.it will work

Comment: @DeepakJha happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
viewpager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
    }, 100);
```

Here 2 is your Fragment C index.

**Update**

No need to create object of viewpager in Fragment A.
Just create one interface that extend in your `Activity` or `Fragment` which contain `ViewPager` and implement it into Fragment A.

Comment: Yes. How can I access the object of viewpager from Fragment A

Answer (score 0):

In your clickHandler add this method    viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)

Comment: How can I get the viewpager object. Its in the main fragmnet which contains the fragment A,B,C of view pager